# How to check if *args[0] exists?

Tags: python, args, keyword-argument

In Python, how can I check if *args[0] exists?

```
def my_fxn(self, *args):
    print(args[0])

my_fxn('ABC')  # this prints 'ABC'
my_fxn()       # this crashes with "IndexError: tuple index out of range"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you work with `*args`, **`*args` will be a tuple** (with zero, one or more elements). The truthiness of a tuple is `True` if it contains **at least one element**. So you can simply write:

```
def my_fxn(self, *args):
    if args:
        print(args[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is:

```py
def my_fxn(self, *args):
    arg0 = args and args[0] or False

# example results
# my_fxn('test', 'b', 12, 15) => 'test'
# my_fxn() => False
```

Not really sure how people feel about this type of overload though.

**EDIT**
A quick explanation as to what is going on. When you look for args on its own it will evaluate to truthy if and only if there is something passed into args. This first test is required to prevent an IndexError: Index out of range error. If there IS something in args it will return the first argument (args[0]). This works even if the argument value in the first position is 'falsey' (f.e. 0, [], etc)

Comment: Doesn't that just evaluate to True or False?

Comment: @Break See my edit for an explanation. Hope that helps!

Comment: I see, interesting. I've been using `args[0] if args else ...` but this is one character shorter so I may use your way from now on

Answer (score 0):

Just need to make sure args exists and has length of 1 or more. Same logic applies if you're looking for args[1]...args[n].

```
def my_fxn(self, *args):
    if args and len(args) > 0:
        print(args[0])
```

**Edit:**

Per Willem's comment `len(args) > 0` is unnecessary if you're looking for `args[0]`.

Comment: You can drop `len(args) > 0`. The truthiness of a collection is True if the collection has at least one element.