# FileChooser crashes Kivy APP when 'back' (to the higher level of dir.) is selected in FileChooserListView: how to fix?

Tags: python, indexing, kivy, filechooser, index-error

I have a Kivy APP that counts words in data files. First, I use FileChooser to select a file (if the file was not selected everything works fine):

```
FileChooserListView:

    canvas.before: 
         Color: 
         rgb: .4, .5, .5
    on_selection: root.select(*args)
```

and then press this:

[image]

and get this error:

```
   File "C:\GUI Projects\wordcount\wordcount.kv", line 53, in <module>
     on_selection: root.select(*args)
   File "wordcount.py", line 15, in select
     filepath = args[1][0]
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

It means this block, the forth line:

```
class DocxPptxWindow(Screen): 
    def select(self, *args):

        filepath = args[1][0]
        text = txt.process(filepath)
        text = text.decode("utf8")
        text = text.replace("\n", " ") #change tags to spaces
        text = text.replace("\t", " ")
        text = text.replace("    ", " ") #delete continous doublespaces
        text = text.replace("   ", " ")
        text = text.replace("  ", " ")
        text = text.split() #convert string into list of words
        word_list = [w for w in text if w.isalnum()] #deleting non-alnum
        num_w = len(word_list)

        try: self.label.text = str(num_w)
        except: pass
```

Obviously, I need to 'close' it somehow, but I have not find it in the [Kivi Tutorial](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html?highlight=filechooser) and apologize in advance for lack of experience.

Or I need to determine the condition under "select" will be executes, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288941/how-to-check-if-args0-exists). But that solution is for `IndexError: tuple index out of range` error, not `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by adding
`if args[1]:`
after
`def select(self, *args):`